# unable to click element when looping

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to loop through all elements, click on them and wait for some time for it to load before collecting some information. However for some reason it only clicks on the first element for all iterations.

```
const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    const data = [];
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-available');
    for (const element of elements) {
        data_sub = [];
        element.click();  
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        let columns = document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-6');
        for(i = 2; i < columns.length; i++){
            let info = columns[i].innerText;
            data_sub.push(info);
        }         
        data.push(data_sub);
    }    
    return data;
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the page URL?

Comment: @vsemozhetbyt https://reslife.ucla.edu/reserve

Comment: I am getting an empty node list in the browser console from the `document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-available')` for this page. Should I click on something before? Or should I be somehow authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems your code is valid, but after each click, DOM tree is somehow redistributed and the next element in loop references the same first element. We can manage this issue in a such way (changed lines are marked by comments):

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://reslife.ucla.edu/reserve');

    const result = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        document.querySelector('.reserve-grid .col-md-4 input').click();
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
        document.querySelector('.reserve-grid .col-md-6 input').click();
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));

        const data = [];
        const length = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-available').length; // <-
        for (let n = 0; n < length; n++) { // <-
            const element = document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-available').item(n); // <-
            data_sub = [];
            element.click();
            await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
            let columns = document.querySelectorAll('.col-md-6');
            for(i = 2; i < columns.length; i++){
                let info = columns[i].innerText;
                data_sub.push(info);
            }
            data.push(data_sub);
        }
        return data;
    });

    console.log(result);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Alternatevely, we can use these lines instead of marked ones

```js
        const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll('.calendar-available')].map(el => el.getAttribute('aria-label')); // <-
        for (const label of labels) { // <-
            const element = document.querySelector(`.calendar-available[aria-label="${label}"]`); // <-
```